# Terminal is not accepting my user password in Elementary os

Tags: release-hera, applications, system, pantheon-terminal, security

elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera

Terminal is not accepting my user password in Elementary os.

Very strange because I have not changed my user password and it also works when I log in.

Have had many installs of Elementary and its the first time this has happened.

I am administrator.

Could this be malicious? and if so what might have happened?

`code` x@Intel:~$ sudo chkrootkit
[sudo] password for x:
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for x:
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Your sudoers file might have gotten incorrectly modified. If that is the case, following [this guide](https://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo) should help fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks...Could this be malicious/ a hack? and if so what might have happened? If it could've been a hack I'd rather just reinstall the OS.

Comment: SSH connection from other computers over the network is not enabled by default, that lowers the chance of an attack. If you have enabled SSH access, and your username and password are easy to guess, and if (big if :)) your network is reachable from the internet, then yes, it is possible (but highly unlikely, in my opinion) that something malicious went down.

Comment: well I typed in: x@Intel:~$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused. So it look like its not but I also have no firewall and I left terminal open :-( I really wanna know how this happened. Unfortunately I have to reboot too because pkexec visudo in terminal wont accept my password.

Comment: I have been removed from sudo and admin.